# How to add created_at in User model in devise on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

There is no created_at column in my user model

```
=> ["id", "email", "encrypted_password", "reset_password_token", "reset_password_sent_at", "remember_created_at", "sign_in_count", "current_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "last_sign_in_ip"]
```

so I created it. But I have no idea where I can add the timestamp in created_at column when create new user.
Any ideas? Thanks~

```
│   ├── users
│   │   ├── _form.html.haml
│   │   ├── _user.html.erb
│   │   ├── create.js.erb
│   │   ├── edit.html.erb
│   │   ├── index.html.haml
│   │   ├── new.html.erb
│   │   ├── runtime_update_user.js.erb
│   │   └── show.html.erb
```

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html in short if you add the column the time stamp should get saved automatically. Can't help for your older records though so either you fill them in yourself or leave them.

Answer (score 0):

if ur migration for user model consists of 't.timestamps' then created_at and updated_at fields are created automatically. if u can, modify the migration and reset the db from start. Or else, add datetime based fields named as above. ActiveRecord will automatically manage these fields when object is created or updated.

Answer (score 0):

In your user model do this:-

```
before_create :add_created_at

private
 def add_created_at
  self.created_at= Time.now
 end
```